# Read Excel file from a starting row using OLEDB Data Provider in C# .Net

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection, oledbcommand, oledbdatareader

I have an excel sheet with dynamicnumber of columns.
I want to read the excel skipping first 2 rows. So starting from rownumber 3 all columns from the excel using OLEDB Data Provider in C# .Net.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to read excel through an Oledb data provider?

Comment: @Iliass Nassibane I want to develop an import functionality reading/ using excel data in ASP.NET. Is there any better option instead of OLEDB Data Provider for reading excel data? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change excel file like adding column that is an Id. After you can insert data autoincreasing number.

[Column ID screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs5Uv.png)

After you can write an SQL script like 'SELECT * FROM [YourSheet$] WHERE Id>2'.(Id is first row so rowNumber>3 is equals to Id>2)